# Will Blink 2 (II) prevent me from getting the achievement Mostly Flesh and Steel?

Tags: achievements, dishonored

> **Mostly Flesh and Steel** 
>   Finish the game without purchasing any supernatural powers or enhancements, besides Blink

I've just finished the game without purchasing anything besides Blink and didn't get the achievement.  Maybe because I "bought" the Blink's upgrade (Blink II) ?
Or is it anything else that I should have been aware of ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Someone has reported (Reddit - /r/dishonored)](http://www.reddit.com/r/dishonored/comments/11qtip/psa_a_few_things_you_should_know_before/) that getting Blink II will indeed stop the *Mostly Flesh and Steel* achievement from unlocking.

[Another report (also from /r/dishonored).](http://www.reddit.com/r/dishonored/comments/11prdc/mainly_flesh_and_steel_question/c6okpq4/)

Also, from the ["*Notes on Stealth Detection, Chaos, and Trophies/Achievements*" post in the Bethesda forums by *Gstaff*](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1415445-notes-on-stealth-detection-chaos-and-trophiesachievements/), an admin and 'Global Community Lead':

> #### I did not receive the ‘Mostly Flesh and Steel’ Achievement/Trophy despite only using the Blink supernatural ability. Why?
>
> - The description reads “besides Blink,” however, this is referring to the initial Blink power that you receive from The Ousider in the
>   Dream. **Purchasing Blink Level 2 will prevent the Achievement/Trophy
>   from unlocking.**
> - Equipping Bone Charms will not count against this Achievement/Trophy.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't get the achievement because you upgraded from Blink I to Blink II.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, your answer could be improved if you can provide a source for the information provided in your answer.