# Does equipping or obtaining bone charms void "Mostly Flesh and Steel"?

Tags: achievements, dishonored

> **Mostly Flesh and Steel**
>
> Finish the game without purchasing any supernatural powers or enhancements, besides Blink

Does obtaining or equipping one of the bone charms you can find throughout the game void this achievement?

Comment: Related: [Will Blink 2 (II) prevent me from getting the achievement Mostly Flesh and Steel?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/89440/4797) Also, see: [Notes on Stealth Detection, Chaos, and Trophies/Achievements](https://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1415445-notes-on-stealth-detection-chaos-and-trophiesachievements/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this achievement refers only to powers, not bone charms.
Note that **`or enhancements`** in this case refers to the Blink Level 2 upgrade.

Do not purchase any new powers, and do not upgrade Blink.
Bone charms are safe.